# Accessing function from widget inside functions wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some widget like this

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: MyWidget
Plugin URI: https:///
Description: 
License: GPL2
*/

// The widget class
class MyWidget extends WP_Widget
{

    // Main constructor
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(
            'mywidgert',
            __('MyWidget', 'password_domain'),
            array(
                'customize_selective_refresh' => true,
            )
        );
    }

    public function form($instance)
    {
    }

    // Update widget settings
    public function update()
    {
    }


    public function widget()
    {

    }

    public function get_user_token()
    {
        return $login_token;
    }
}

function register_my_widget()
{
    register_widget('MyWidget');
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'register_my_widget');
```

When i try to access some function from class MyWiget inside another fucntion that is not inside class like this

```
function export_database(){
 $this->get_user_token();
}
```

I got 500 error also i have tried something like this

```
$widget = new MyWidget();
$widget->get_user_token();
```

Again i got error 500, how to access in my function **export_database** some other function from class MyWidget, please also keep in mind this is wordpress, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using add_action, first you register the action before the theme files are loaded :

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: MyWidget
Plugin URI: https:///
Description: 
License: GPL2
*/

add_action( 'init', array ( 'MyWidget', 'init' ) );

// The widget class
class MyWidget extends WP_Widget
{
    ...
}
```

Then you can register your action in the construct function like below :

```
// Main constructor
public function __construct()
{
    ...
    add_action( 'get_user_token', array ( $this, 'get_user_token' ), 10, 1 );
}
```

You can finally call `do_action( 'get_user_token', 50 );` in your theme or another plugin.

See this related post : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44708/using-a-plugin-class-inside-a-template